# Performance of Scalar function in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

We have the below scalar function which is used in most of our select queries. I have added only a single `IF` condition but this function has around 50 `IF` statements. I tried to convert it to inline but failed at the last statement for `@output`.

This function is causing performance issues. So need to convert this to an inline function.

We currently using Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Nov 16, 2022, 04:43:19   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation

```
     CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[udf_GetLSLineDescByGUIDLocalised] (  
            @ComputationID   INT,  
            @AccountGUID   UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,  
            @LSCode    nvarchar(50),  
         @SpecificLevelOnly INT = -1,   --defaults to full description  
         @LanguageID   INT  
        )    
        RETURNS nvarchar(1000)   
        
        AS    
        BEGIN   
          
            DECLARE @Output   nvarchar(1000)  
          
         DECLARE @FormatToken NVARCHAR(50)  
          
         SELECT @FormatToken = ResourceString  
         FROM dbo.tbl_ResourceString WITH(NOLOCK)  
         WHERE ResourceKey = 'General.AccountSeparator' AND LanguageID = @LanguageID  
          
            -------------------------------------------  
            -- Balance Sheet  
            -------------------------------------------  
            if @LSCode = 'BS' begin  
          
                select TOP 1 @Output =     
           case  
            when @SpecificLevelOnly > 0 then   
             case   
              when @SpecificLevelOnly = 1 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l1.AccountGUID, l1.Description, @LanguageID)  
              when @SpecificLevelOnly = 2 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l2.AccountGUID, l2.Description, @LanguageID)  
              when @SpecificLevelOnly = 3 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l3.AccountGUID, l3.Description, @LanguageID)  
              when @SpecificLevelOnly = 4 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l4.AccountGUID, l4.Description, @LanguageID)  
              when @SpecificLevelOnly = 5 and ls.Level5ID <> 0 then dbo.udf_AccountName(ls.AccountGUID, ls.Description, @LanguageID)  
             end  
            else  
                     case   
                         when l2.Description is null then dbo.udf_AccountName(l1.AccountGUID, l1.Description, @LanguageID)  
                         else dbo.udf_AccountName(l1.AccountGUID, l1.Description, @LanguageID) + @formatToken   
                     end +   
                     case   
                         when nullif(l2.Description, 'BLANK')is null then ''  
                         when l3.Description is null then dbo.udf_AccountName(l2.AccountGUID, l2.Description, @LanguageID)  
                         else dbo.udf_AccountName(l2.AccountGUID, l2.Description, @LanguageID) + @formatToken   
                     end +  
                     case   
                         when l3.Description is null then ''  
             when ls.Level4ID = 0 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l3.AccountGUID, l3.Description, @LanguageID)  
                         else dbo.udf_AccountName(l3.AccountGUID, l3.Description, @LanguageID) + @formatToken  
                     end +   
               case   
                         when l4.Description is null then ''  
             when ls.Level5ID = 0 then dbo.udf_AccountName(l4.AccountGUID, l4.Description, @LanguageID)  
                         else dbo.udf_AccountName(l4.AccountGUID, l4.Description, @LanguageID) + @formatToken  
                     end +   
            case   
             when ls.Level5ID <> 0 then dbo.udf_AccountName(ls.AccountGUID, ls.Description, @LanguageID)   
             else ''   
            end  
           end         
             from tbl_ScheduleBS ls WITH (NOLOCK)  
              
             left outer join dbo.tbl_ScheduleBS l1  WITH (NOLOCK)  
             on  ls.ComputationID = l1.ComputationID   
             and ls.Level1ID = l1.Level1ID   
             and l1.Level2ID = 0  
              
             left outer join dbo.tbl_ScheduleBS l2  WITH (NOLOCK)  
                on  ls.ComputationID = l2.ComputationID   
             and ls.Level1ID = l2.Level1ID   
             and ls.Level2ID = l2.Level2ID and l2.Level2ID <> 0  
             and l2.Level3ID = 0  
              
             left outer join dbo.tbl_ScheduleBS l3 WITH (NOLOCK)  
                on  ls.ComputationID = l3.ComputationID   
             and ls.Level1ID = l3.Level1ID   
             and ls.Level2ID = l3.Level2ID and l3.Level2ID <> 0  
             and ls.Level3ID = l3.Level3ID and l3.Level3ID <> 0  
             and l3.Level4ID = 0  
               
         left outer join dbo.tbl_ScheduleBS l4 WITH (NOLOCK)  
                on  ls.ComputationID = l4.ComputationID   
             and ls.Level1ID = l4.Level1ID   
             and ls.Level2ID = l4.Level2ID and l4.Level2ID <> 0  
             and ls.Level3ID = l4.Level3ID and l4.Level3ID <> 0  
             and ls.Level4ID = l4.Level4ID and l4.Level4ID <> 0  
         and l4.Level5ID = 0  
              
                where ls.ComputationID = @ComputationID  
                and ls.AccountGUID = @AccountGUID  
          
            
           
            -------------------------------------------  
            -- Unknown @LSCode, perhaps not implemented yet?  
            -------------------------------------------  
            end else begin  
          
                -- can't raise errors from within a function, return null   
                select TOP 1 @Output = NULL  
          
            end  
              
         select @Output = case when @Output like  @formattoken + '%' then stuff(@Output, 1, 3, '') else @Output end   
              
            return @Output  
          
        END
```

Comment: Yes, multi-line scalar functions can perform *very* poorly. In Azure SQL Database and SQL Server 2019+ you *can* inline scalar functions, but they come with (many) caveats. For the above, you would be much better off changing your function to an **inline** table value function.

Comment: Side note as well, default values for parameters in user-defined functions are pretty much pointless; the only way you can define you want the default value is to use the `DEFAULT` operator, passing `NULL` will explicitly pass `NULL` and SQL Server doesn't support function overriding.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: I just noticed as well that your function calls another function (`dbo.udf_AccountName`); without knowing what that does, you may well need to `ALTER` that, or (probably better) repeat the logic from that function. SQL isn't a programming language, and it *does not* benefit from things like using functions to call functions (to call functions); it might make your code shorter, but in T-SQL it can come at a *significant* cost to performance when you nest such objects. Nested `VIEW`s, for example, can perform terribly.

Comment: thanks @Larnu - I tried to convert to inline by using case but stuck in the last line

Comment: To switch to an inline table-value function you need to *completely* rewrite the entire function, @omkar .